# Passthru works in development server but not in apache

Tags: php, apache2, laravel

I'm trying to execute a Python script from a Laravel project in Ubuntu 20.04 using this code:

```
passthru('/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/birra/public/setauto.py DB_D1 false');
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

This works perfectly in Laravel Development Server but for some reason it won't work in Apache. I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933082/exec-function-within-laravel-works-wrong-in-tinker-and-console-properly) where someone suggested it could be a permission problem so I granted all just to check, and made www-data owner.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data aid-pc     925 Jan 22 13:51 setauto.py
```

I also copied the cli php.ini to apache's php.ini. Restarted apache and tried `config:clear`. None of these worked. Any idea of why is this happening and how could I solve it?

This shows no error, just passes as if everything went right but the script is clearly not executed since it should have affected some variables that remain the same. It also returns `output=""`

I also tried enabling CGI in Apache for python scripts as shown [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/cgi.html), but it still behaves the same way.

Comment: Where is your error checking? Go back and debug your code.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Actually, as I mentioned in the question, this works perfectly in Laravel's development server, it just doesn't work in Apache, it also shows no error, this makes me think this is not a code error but something with apache's configuration

Comment: You do not even get the return value from `passthru()`!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I do in the development server.

Comment: You deleted your error checking for "production"?! You need it there too!

Comment: No, no I didn't delete it! it's still there simply in dev server `$output` shows the expected value but in Apache it returns `""`